# Can I relieve some clutter in this file and get the smallest amount of lines possible for these classes?

Tags: c#

I have the following file that contains the following classes. A lot of these classes do nearly identical things, but I'm struggling to figure out how to clean them up. What can I do to relieve the clutter in the file and get the smallest amount of lines possible without sacrificing functionality?

```
namespace My_Project {
    // A simple class used to give the other classes the letter value.
    public class LetterValue : IEquatable<LetterValue> {
        public char Letter;

        public LetterValue(char c) {
            Letter = c;
        }
        public bool Equals(LetterValue other) => Letter == other.Letter;
    }

    // An extention of LetterValue that adds a score variable.
    public class LetterScore : LetterValue, IEquatable<LetterScore> {
        public uint Score;
        public LetterScore(char c, uint score) : base(c) {
            Letter = c;
            Score = score;
        }
        public override string ToString() => $"[LETTER:{Letter} | SCORE:{Score}]";

        // TO USE THE .COMPARE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FILE
        public bool Equals(LetterScore other) => Letter == other.Letter && Score == other.Score;
    }

    // An extension to LetterValue that adds a coordinate variable.
    public class LetterPoint : LetterValue, IEquatable<LetterPoint> {
        public Coordinate Position;

        public LetterPoint(char c, Coordinate point) : base(c) {
            Letter = c;
            Position = point;
        }
        public override string ToString() => $"{Letter} {Position}";

        // TO USE THE .COMPARE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FILE
        public bool Equals(LetterPoint other) => Letter == other.Letter && Position.Equals(other.Position);
    }

    // WORDTYPE ENUM
    public enum WordIntersectType { None, Intersecting, NonIntersecting }

    // An extension to LetterPoint that adds an additional value.
    public class LetterPointIntersecting : IEquatable<LetterPointIntersecting> {
        public LetterPoint LetterPoint;
        public WordIntersectType WordIntersecting;
        public LetterPointIntersecting(LetterPoint point, WordIntersectType intersectType = WordIntersectType.None) {
            LetterPoint = point;
            WordIntersecting = intersectType;
        }
        public override string ToString() => $"{LetterPoint} {WordIntersecting}";

        // TO USE THE .COMPARE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FILE
        public bool Equals(LetterPointIntersecting other) => LetterPoint.Equals(other.LetterPoint) && WordIntersecting == other.WordIntersecting;
    }

    // An extension to LetterScore that adds an additional value.
    public class LetterScoreIntersecting : IEquatable<LetterScoreIntersecting> {
        public LetterScore LetterScore;
        public WordIntersectType WordIntersecting;
        public LetterScoreIntersecting(LetterScore score, WordIntersectType intersectType = WordIntersectType.None) {
            LetterScore = score;
            WordIntersecting = intersectType;
        }
        public override string ToString() => $"{LetterScore} {WordIntersecting}";

        // TO USE THE .COMPARE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN FILE
        public bool Equals(LetterScoreIntersecting other) => LetterScore.Equals(other.LetterScore) && WordIntersecting == other.WordIntersecting;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the code works, try using Code Review instead.

Comment: *“these classes do nearly identical things”* – I would say they all don’t really do anything. It’s just boilerplate stuff that you cannot really remove if you want to keep the separate types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all your different kinds of letter extensions with a single class.  The extending value will be typed using a generic parameter.

```
public class LetterExtension<T> : LetterValue, IEquatable<LetterExtension<T>> {
    public T Extension { get; set; }

    public LetterExtension(char c, T extension) : base(c) {
        this.Extension = extension;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Letter} {Extension}";

    public bool Equals(LetterExtension<T> other) => 
        Letter == other.Letter && Extension.Equals(other.Extension);
}
```